# Можно ли задать альтернативный текст при наведении на блок?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли задать альтернативный текст при наведении на блок?

У тега img есть атрибут alt, при наведении курсора на картинку всплывает тест установленный в этом атрибуте. Можно ли сделать такое для блока? Т.е. нужно картинку заменить на блок с бэкграундом с сохранением поведения.

Comment: гугли тултипы,всплывающие подсказки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div title="здесь текст"></div>
```

Comment: Это не ответ.

Comment: А чё заминусовали? Каков вопрос таков ответ! Тег div поддерживает атрибут title.

Comment: Ну можно еще самому создать всё что угодно используя javascript. При наведении вызвать функцию, а там выводить анимацией всплывающий текст, делать задержку перед показом, менять цвет и.т.д


<script>
function functi(text)
{
alert(text);
}
</script>

<div onmouseover="functi('здесь текст')"></div>

Comment: А этот комментарий зря... Был бы он ответом я бы третий минус поставил! Думайте прежде чем что-то делать!

Comment: Я об этом и спрашивал. Глупость, но я как-то не знал и не подумал о том, что у div'а есть такой атрибут.